# Apache: On forcing www - Does it make sense to exclude generic files?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I force www. on requests inside mydomain/httpdocs/. Does it make sense to exclude generic files from this rule?

Technically such don't need the www. Maybe for SEO?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|tif|bmp|flv|pdf|mp3|ogg|m4a|wav|js|css|xml)$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it does not. You are simply adding an extra `RewriteCond` directive. An extra `mod_rewrite` rule to be processed.